# Laravel 5.6 chunk with groupBy

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am getting the error while executing below, while without groupBy it is working fine.

```
    User::select('col')->groupBy('col1')->chunk(100, function ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            dump($user);
        }
    });
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
```

Comment: You may need to select `col1` in addition to `col` before you can `groupBy('col1')`

Comment: If you use `chunk()` on a query without an `ORDER BY` clause, Laravel uses the primary key by default. Try `->orderBy('col1')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like that need to use orderBy

```
User::select('col')
    ->orderBy('col1')
    ->groupBy('col1')
    ->chunk(100, function ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            // code ..
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is working fine for me mysql 5.7.22 and laravel 6.18.10

Comment: Ok, let's decide the audience if your vote goes up I will definitely mark your answer.

Comment: Works for me... orderBy is a must if you use groupBy + chunk

Comment: ^This is the correct answer. Thank you @Jonas Staudenmeir for your comment above and bhavinjr for this answer.